# jQuery selector for element thats not on every page.

Tags: jquery

I have the following code. Its working fine but im wondering if the 3rd line is best practice. When the element myID is on the page its attributes is changed. However its not on every page so often this does nothing. This seems harmless to me but are there any downsides im not aware of?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < 700) {
            $('#myID').attr('size', 1)
        }
    });
```

Comment: That's no problem for me. Because the `attr` method is called for each element inside jQuery object. If the jQuery object is empty there's no problem

Comment: The only reason I ask is I think ive seen a little warning sign with IE when I use jQuery selectors for elements that dont exist on every page. This was on a different project though so I cant remember 100%.

Comment: I think the `attr()` does a foreach on its results, so that shouldn't hurt. And it would be weird if jQuery made a selector that caused errors, bc its one of the most basic operations.

Comment: @EricG yes, my mistake. However my official answer is correct (I think :))

Comment: @chumkiu I was talking to jdln, but reading your answer made me upvote it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [jquery attr doc](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

> The .attr() method gets the attribute value for only the first element
>   in the matched set. To get the value for each element individually,
>   use a looping construct such as jQuery's .each() or .map() method.

The `.attr()` method try to set attribute on the first element of jquery object. If jquery object is empty then nothing happens.

Comment: I've edited because prev answer was incorrect. `Undefined` is the value returned at GET attr (and not SET).

Answer (score 2):

You could, just to be sure, check for the existence of the object before you perform any action on it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 700 && $('#myID').length) {
        $('#myID').attr('size', 1);
    }
});
```